# Three Column DIV - is nesting necessary?

Tags: css, html

I have a general question regarding the three column DIV layout.

From what I've read online, a common practice seems to be something like this:

```
.container {
  .left {
     //content
  }
  .other {
    .center {
      //content
    }
    .right {
      //content
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, two columns are always nested within a second container.    However, I have some code that looks like this, and it appears to work just fine.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfsamet/dCzE4/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        Left<br>Content<br>Section
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        Center<br>Content<br>Center<br>Content<br>Center<br>Content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right<br>Content<br>Section
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    max-width:800px;
}
.left {
    background-color:#FF6666;
    float:left;
    width:10%;
}
.center {
    background-color:#66FF66;
    float:left;
    width:70%
}
.right {
    background-color:#6666FF;
    float:right;
    width:20%;
}
```

So, my question is this:

Is there a reason to need to nest every two DIV elements inside another container? 
And is there any downside to using the approach I'm using now?

As far as I can tell... there is nothing wrong with it, but would like to hear what the community has to say, and am I going to experience some trouble down the line.

Comment: Apart from site-specific considerations with sizing-to-fit the 2 solutions are generally equivalent. For some cases the nesting might be required, but that's not a general 'must or must not do'.

Comment: to be honest I never saw this css nesting, I think it is not necessary but I', really excited what experts here think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with the comment Niels Keurentjes provided, there is no reason why this isn't 'allowed'. It could be be useful for some (responsive) designs to wrap more divs in one.

The code you provided can also be optimized, dropping the container div and use your body as the wrapper:

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    ...
</div>
<div class="center">
    ...
</div>
<div class="right">
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* delete the .container style */
body {
    width:100%;
    max-width:800px;
}
```

Also check this [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dCzE4/3/).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point.   I guess there really isn't a need here to have the container DIV.